# Pod's memory is not released after high load is gone

Tags: kubernetes, hpa

I'm playing around Kubernetes HorizontalPodAutoscaler. When scaling by the CPU utilization, everything is working fine. However, when I'm trying to scale by memory utilization, my app only scales up. After the load is gone (some concurrent requests), the pods memory is not released. The `kubectl top pods` command shows that pods uses the same memory usage as it was under the load. And, my cluster cannot be scaled down.

I've got the same behavior with simple node.js app (expressJS web server), and ASP.NET WebApi app.

Here are my deployment and HPA manifests:

deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-api-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testapiproject
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testapiproject
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: testapiproject
        image: ostashev/testapiproject:latest
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 30Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 300m
            memory: 100Mi
```

HPA:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
 name: app-api-hpa
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: app-api-depl
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 20
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 75
```

Comment: To me it looks more like a Node JS question than a Kubernetes one as the HPA works as intended, it is the application that does not go down in memory. I suggest you add the appropriate Node JS tags to have the best answers.

Comment: The same problem. App written in Rust and tested in local machine with successful memory releasing. But in container/pod (Debian) it doesn't work. Only reason what I found - restart pod if app was involved in heavy calculation before.